# Complexe child_process not working with Promise bluebird

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluebird, child-process, electron

I wan't to execute a shell command using child_process from node.js https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html, I am doing an electron program using React JS.

I want to do a Promise with bluebird, my function works but just for a small command like 'ls' but if I want to execute a simple hello world program in a folder I want to do something like : `cd localbuild/login/ && java Main`. It's working on my terminal. When I tried to do that in my function I have this error : `promise rejected: Error: spawn cd localbuild/login/ ENOENT closing code: -2`.

Here is my function :

```
_compile(command){

    var Promise = require('bluebird');
    var exec = require('child_process').execFile;

    var pathFile = "cd localbuild/login/";

    function promiseFromChildProcess(child) {
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        child.addListener("error", reject);
        child.addListener("exit", resolve);
      });
    }
    var child = exec(pathFile+ " && "+command);

    //var child = exec('ls'); // It works

    promiseFromChildProcess(child).then(function (result) {
      console.log('promise complete: ' + result);
    }, function (err) {
      console.log('promise rejected: ' + err);
    });

    child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
      console.log('stdout: ' + data);
    });
    child.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
      console.log('stdout: ' + data);
    });
    child.on('close', function (code) {
      console.log('closing code: ' + code);
    });
}
```

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function of the child_process library you are importing is execFile, but you use it to run a shell command and not to run an executable file.

Just change :

```
var exec = require('child_process').execFile;
```

To:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
```

And it should work!